# Attaching validation to EF objects used in MVC controllers/views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We're throwing together a quick project (CRUD forms) and decided to skip view models and use EF entities directly in controllers and views. Since I'm not used to this approach, I'm confused about handling validation.

For example: a DB field has a length of 25. How does that get transferred (if it can) to a validation constraint in my view? If i was using an intermediate model, I would attach attributes to the model properties and it would work. How would I do this using EF objects directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using MetadataType attribute on the Ef generated classes. The EF generates partial classes. So those can be extended and attribute added to it. Then another "buddy class" can be written that can have member decoration. For example

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EFGeneratedClass_MetaData))]
public partial class EFGeneratedClass
{
}

public partial class EFGeneratedClass_MetaData
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Member1 Display")]
    public string Member1 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a link to more information on this? Thanks!

Comment: Just to add. It seems adding the public visibility modifier to the property name does the trick. I forgot I removed it and was going nuts wondering why it was no longer working. Thanks!

Comment: I had forgotten to mark the properties Public, too, and it was driving me nuts trying to figure out why they wouldn't validate! By the way, Scott Guthrie did a blog post on validation metadata and buddy classes when MVC 2 first came out (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).

Comment: How should this be done if your domain model are in a different project than your web project?  Do they both need to be in the same namespace?

Comment: This is using the partial classes. Partial classes can't span multiple projects so this won't work in that case.

Comment: It seems like if the namespaces don't match up, there would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is to use the DataAnnotations attributes that are in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations anmespace.

MVC respects those and will populate your ModelError collection if any fail.  In the case of your example, you could add a using statement for that namespace and then just flag a property with

```
[StringLength(25)]
```

and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a partial 'buddy' meta class and decorate it with validation attributes.

For example, say your entity was 'Foo':

```
[MetadataType(typeof(FooMetadata))]
public partial class Foo {}

public class FooMetadata
{
    //apply validation attributes to properties
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 25)]
    [DisplayName("Some Neato Property")]
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

For more information see this link on MSDN:

[Customize Data Field Validation in the Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488527.aspx)

Cheers.