# viewmodels and unobtrusive validation mvc3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm unable to get unobtrusive validation to work using custom viewModels representing abstractions of my EF generated classes.

As try as I might, the validation is not firing on form submission for the property `Name` in my City entity. I believe it is has something to do with the different models in the views but I simply don't know enough how it all works.

Please note. I have all the latest validation scripts and when observing the page using firebug and firequery I can see that the script is adding and removing the class valid from the input but that the input is not part of the validation collection.

Many thanks in advance.

My viewModel:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents abstraction of the City View that also serves in
/// data binding between the City View and the City Model.
/// </summary>
public class CityViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the city.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    public City City { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of states.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    public ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

My CreateCity view:

```
@model OzFarmGuide.ViewModels.CityViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create a new city";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Create a new city</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { States = Model.States })
    <div class="entity-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Cities")
    </div>
}
```

My Editor template: (_ValidationPartial just contains the script references)

```
@model OzFarmGuide.Models.City
@Html.Partial("_ValidationPartial")
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("StateId",
    new SelectList(ViewBag.States as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
    "StateId", "Name",
    Model.StateId))
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CityId)
```

As requested here are the scripts I have included:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What Js scripts have you included? I have a feeling that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is not included.

Comment: @amit_g: I didn't have that script included but as far as I was aware that was only needed for ajax posts. I've added the reference but sadly there is no change.

Comment: Could you post exactly what scripts are included? These probably would be in _AdminLayout.cshtml.

Comment: @amit: Will do, I'm at work at the moment so it'll be another few hours. Cheers

Comment: @amit: I've included the scripts in my question

Comment: Add <script src=”@Url.Content(“~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js”)” type=”text/javascript”></script>
<script src=”@Url.Content(“~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js”)” type=”text/javascript”></script>

Comment: @Amit: My apologies for the late reply. That doesn't help either. I'm convinced it has something to so with me having a different model in my editor template. Not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: Name field would be string. Do you have [Required] data annotation on it? If not, it would not be mandatory field and thus would not trigger the validation.

Comment: @Amit: The models are generated using the entity framework so I can't edit them easily directly. The field in the db is markedd as required.

Comment: You can make a buddy class, to add the data annotations. Add [MetadataType(buddyClassName)] to your EntityModel Partial class.

Comment: Look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974139/attaching-validation-to-ef-objects-used-in-mvc-controllers-views/4974250#4974250) at how to create the buddy class to add the Required attributes and other Data Annotations in EF generated classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [Required] data annotations on all reference types and string types. As you mentioned that your classes are EF generated. For that use buddy class. Look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974139/attaching-validation-to-ef-objects-used-in-mvc-controllers-views/4974250#4974250) in another similar question.

Comment: Truly outstanding support! Thanks so much for that. It really was a showstopping bug. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1- For string properties you should add [Required].

2- Can you check if you are having multiple input fields with the same name "Name", this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the following ?

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You can also turn them on or off with code:

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

Also, have you added any of the required data annotations to your properties ?

[Brad Wilson On Unobtrusive Validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)